# How to find a document in Sanity (groq) that has a value between two numbers

Tags: javascript, sanity, groq

How do you query for a document using GROQ when the document has a value e.g. Width and you want to query for all documents that have a width value between 500 and 700 for example.

It seems there isn't a built in method to do this or maybe it's not yet documented?